# How to Use AJAX or Dynamic Actions to Refresh one Table on a Page in Oracle Apex?

Tags: ajax, oracle-apex

I have two Main reports. Each report has a corresponding region with a Nonmain Classic report (so 4 reports total). Clicking on a link in each of the Main reports reveals details in its corresponding Nonmain report.

Currently, clicking on a Main report will reload the whole page, and all the PL/SQL and SQL has to refire from all 4 reports.

It would cut down on the SQL calls if only the nonmain report refreshed. I assume AJAX would be the best bet to accomplish this.

How would I go about doing such a task?

Thank you.

P.S., all four reports are determined by a PL/SQL function returning a SQL statement. All headings also are determined by a PL/SQL function returning a colon-delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your previous questions in mind, your classic reports rely on the session state of some page items. You are setting the value of these items in your colunmn links.
If you want to cut out the submit of the page then you need a way for the anchor tags to not fire their default action and provide the value for page items to be set to a dynamic action.

You have to put this in the column link attributes:

```
onclick="return false;#" class="reportlink1"
```

You then need to pass on some data, and i suggest using data tags

```
data-value1="#COL1#:"
```

Create a dynamic action, firing on click and uses a jQuery selector `.reportlink1`

What needs to happen now is to provide the page items with their needed values
Add a true action to execute javascript:

```
 var lValue1 = $(this.triggeringElement).data("value1");
 $("P1_ITEM1").val(lValue1)
```

With the item value set, create another true action of type "Refresh" and set it to affect your secondary report.
The final step is then to set the "Page items to submit" on the secondary report. This will cause the report to submit the values of the set page items to the session and ensures that the sql will return the correct values when the region is refreshed.

Comment: Thanks again Tom. I've been asked to put out a fire but will hopefully implement this tonight, or at most tomorrow.

Comment: Hey Tom, thank you for putting me on the right track. For some reason, I couldn't use `$("P1_ITEM1").val(1Value1);` and then set the Page Items to submit on the secondary report; I had to use AJAX in the secondary report as my answer below shows. I assume this is a peculiarity reflecting the complexities / mistakes on my page. Can you speculate why it wouldn't work?

Comment: Odd that it would not work. If possible, try it again but now look at the "Session" tab from the developer bar, and see if the values are actually reaching the session state. If they don't, make sure that the value is correctly changing for the input item value by inspecting it in the DOM. And hopefully `1Value1` is a typo of yours :-)

Comment: I did check the session state and the values did change. When I'm back at work I'll check it out again and describe what happened.

Comment: Can't figure it out @Tom. Anyways, now I would like to be able to set the REQUEST using ajax, as in the followup question here, if you know how:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764145/is-there-any-way-to-set-request-using-ajax-in-oracle-apex

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Tom's approach did not work for me; I assume it must be the idiosyncrasies of my page. If anyone stumbles upon this question, try Tom's method first, and if for some reason it doesn't work then try the following adaptation with AJAX in the dynamic action:

If your nonmain reports rely on the session state of some page items, and those items are set via column links from your main report, you must put this in the column link attributes to prevent the submission of the page and to pass the values using data tags:

```
onclick="return false;" class="reportlink1" data-value1="#COL01#" data-value2="#COL02#"
```

Create a dynamic action, firing on click and using a JQuery selector `.reportlink1`

Provide the page items with their needed values **VIA AJAX**. Add a true action to execute synchronous javascript:

```
 var v1 = $(this.triggeringElement).data("value1");
 var v2 = $(this.triggeringElement).data("value2");
 var get = new htmldb_Get(null, &APP_ID., 'APPLICATION_PROCESS=dummy', &APP_PAGE_ID.);
 get.add('PX_ITEM1' , v1)
 get.add('PX_ITEM2', v2);
 gReturn = get.get();
 get = null;
```

With the item values set, create another true action of type "Refresh" and set it to affect the secondary report.

Unlike Tom's solution, DO NOT set the Page Items to Submit on the secondary report.