# Is there any way to set REQUEST using AJAX in Oracle Apex?

Tags: ajax, oracle-apex

This question follows off [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616423/how-to-use-ajax-or-dynamic-actions-to-refresh-one-table-on-a-page-in-oracle-apex).

I have a main report with a column link, that when clicked, refreshes a secondary report with a dynamic action that a) executes JavaScript which calls AJAX to set the page items that the secondary report uses to construct a SQL statement and b) refreshes the report.

There is actually 2 tertiary reports as subregions in the secondary report, conditionally visible only when the REQUEST = a certain value.

I call AJAX to set page items without having to refresh the page using this method:

```
 var get = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,'APPLICATION_PROCESS=dummy',&APP_PAGE_ID.);
 get.add('PX_ITEM', 'new value');
 gReturn = get.get();
 get = null;
```

I was hoping that there would be something as simple as the following to use AJAX to set the REQUEST for that page

```
get.add('PX_REQUEST', 'new value');
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what the problem is. Do you want to be able to dynamically switch between the 2 of them by setting the request value?

Comment: @Tom A column link in the main report was setting the REQUEST feature using the f?p syntax; but now that the report is refreshed using a dynamic action, the link is not submitted and the REQUEST feature is not set. The tertiary report is conditional on the REQUEST being a certain value. I would like to set the REQUEST feature via AJAX if it is possible.

Comment: The thing is that, if your report is conditional and this condition is based on a request, then you're out of luck. First of all because the region's condition would fail at render time, causing no html to be generated for this region. This means that there would be nothing to refresh too. There simply is no html element to trigger something on, and changing the request will not automatically display the report. Not sure what would happen when refreshing the containing region though, would need to try. Secondly: an ajax call (or htmldb_Get) use the ajax request to set the APPLICATION_PROCESS !